# Interchanging sum and Riemann Integral

Tags: definite-integrals

The question: Is there a theorem that allows you to interchange sum and integral for positive functions sequences, but the theorem and it's proof only involves riemann or riemann stieljes integrals.
Or if Fubini and Tonelli theorems have a "Riemann" form and proof.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at
http://planetmath.org/criterionforinterchangingsummationandintegration
It is a quite good clarification.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but planetmath uses measure theory. Isn't there a theorem of interchanging sum and integral just for Riemann integrable functions?

Comment: For this specific case, I really do not know. Sorry for that.

Comment: It's okay. Thank you for your time.